# Is there a word for the object of a dilettante?

Tags: single-word-requests

A dilettante is currently defined as:

> "a person who cultivates an area of interest, such as the arts, without real commitment or knowledge" - OED, online (2020) version

However the etymology is from the word "delight".

(I believe, but don't know, it did not always have the contemporary negative connotation, which I believe, but don't know, it has.)

I'm looking for a word that describes what a dilettante or dabbler might be dabbling in, without entailing interest. Here's an example. My skills include writing a balance sheet, professional taxes, and forensic auditing, while my ___ include astronomy and metaphysics.

Interests and hobbies imply interest, which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: I'm confused by "...without entailing interest."  Why would a dilettante know a little about something they are not interested in (at least superficially)? Are you asking about a poseur? Or are these subjects that the person happens to know a little bit about, perhaps because they were forced to learn it in school?  If it's the latter, I'd rephrase: "...and I have some familiarity with astronomy and metaphysics."

Comment: Yeah, forced to learn it in school is a good example of how you might dabble without being interested. Or you were interested in it last year, but the shine dulled. Familiarity works.

Comment: I suggested the synonyms, but it was @ricky from the Answers who came up with "amateur interests" (My comment was based on that). They are owed thanks.

Comment: @sameagol You should maybe update your question (or even create a new question) because the "without entailing interest" part is getting lost. A dilettante *is* interested in what they're doing, just on a superficial level. It's almost the opposite of something that you were forced to study.

Comment: @sameagol: I'm not sure why you would bother doing or even mentioning something in which you have no interest. What is your goal?

Comment: Why would someone be dabbling in anything if they weren’t interested in it?

Comment: Why not "hobbies"?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because unfortunately confused from top to bottom.

Comment: @Hearth It's in the question: *"Interests and hobbies imply interest, which I'm trying to avoid."*

Comment: "Dilettante" is mildly pejorative, so someone is unlikely to use the word you are looking for about their own interests, unless they are engaging in mock self-deprecation. Also some dilettantes do become very interested in things, but they quickly become bored and move on to something else.

Comment: When I was aged 16, I acquired a tortoiseshell cigarette holder. My father said I should not use it in public, because people might think I was a 'dilettante'. I think he meant 'homosexual' (it was 1968). Noël Coward was famous for his cigarette holders in the 1930s.

Comment: How do I dispute the edits made to my own question?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I suggest *dabblings*, a word that you approach in your question, and one that fits your specification well.

> dabbling noun
>
> a superficial or intermittent interest, investigation, or experiment
>
> “his dabblings in philosophy and art”
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dabbling)

Among my own dabblings is an interest in English language and usage.

Comment: There is a parallel in writing. Readers of this site may be amused by my *scribblings* rather than my *writing*.

Comment: I don't know if I'm sold on that M-W definition, as it seems to contradict their own example. If you dabble in English language and usage, or in philosophy and art, then your dabblings would be the products of that dabbling: The actions you take or output you create while pursuing that interest. Like this answer, for example. (Compare with "scribblings", as offered by Anton: "My scribblings" would still be _things I've written_, not my passing interest in writing itself.)

Answer (score 7):

My ***professional skills*** include writing a balance sheet, taxes, and forensic auditing. Astronomy and metaphysics are among my ***amateur interests***.

Answer (score 7):

*Dilettante* is a bit of a pejorative (as you noted), so you probably don't want to invoke that.

How about *avocation*?

> **1 :** a subordinate occupation pursued in addition to one's vocation especially for enjoyment : HOBBY
> <sub>Source: Merriam-Webster [avocation](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/avocation)</sub>

Example: *My professional expertise includes balance sheet writing, tax preparation, and forensic auditing. Among my avocational pursuits are astronomy and metaphysics.*

Or maybe just: *My professional expertise includes balance sheet writing, tax preparation, and forensic auditing. In my spare time I enjoy studying astronomy and metaphysics.*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117886/discussion-on-answer-by-tinfoil-hat-is-there-a-word-for-the-object-of-a-dilettan).

Answer (score 7):

What a dilettante does is their "pastime". ("an activity that someone does regularly for enjoyment rather than work; a hobby" -- from Oxford Languages)

I don't know of a single word for what you're actually requesting, though. Usually it would be a phrase or implied...perhaps in an "About the Author" (or artist, or developer, etc.) page. "She earned her degree in financial accounting at Made Up University; but has happily not used this skill at all as a writer of technical manuals."

Answer (score 3):

A **diversion** can be ‘A hobby; an activity that distracts the mind.’ ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/diversion#Noun))

(As @sameagol mentioned, the related French word ‘divertissement’, [meaning](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/divertissement#Noun) an entertaining diversion, is also used in English, though I think very rarely.)

Answer (score 3):

I've heard of "enthusiasm" being used (by the dilettante's long-suffering wife) in this context.

Reference in response to an "improve this post" notice: Liverpool Daily Post, circa 1973, writing on a local man who dressed as a samurai and made paper flowers.

Comment: This site encourages users to do some research for their answers. You can give links of sites or dictionaries where you actually found the information of giving. A simple memory is not enough for your answer to be convincing.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest **hobbyhorse**

> a. A favorite hobby.

> b. A topic that one frequently brings up or dwells on; a fixation.

[AHD]